# PCI compliance - use of ANSI X9.17 for export keys

Tags: keys, key-exchange, key-derivation

we have a concern about a key export.
We completed the migration to Key Block LMK in our environment (with HSM Thales 10K).
Now, we have to exchange keys with third-parties that still use Keys in variant form.
We generated the keys and formed the ZMK using the Key Block standard. To resolve the issue we have to export keys using "X" Key Scheme.

> About compliance, we are still exporting keys in the correct key
> block format? or using the "X" we are converting them for the export?

It may seem like an excess of attention, but the fact that exports with scheme X must be authorized has raised safety concerns.
it would be interesting to have a technical clarification on the use of scheme X